# MySQL nested selection clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing an exercise but I am stuck on this problem and I got an error message. Here the link to database and my query

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39881/2

I am supposed to delete the Mazda belonging to John Smith. Can anybody help me out what's wrong with my query? Thanks a lot.

Comment: delete car `from` where? also, use `'` instead of `’` and `driver_id` instead of `driver-id`

Answer (score 2):

if I'm understanding you correctly you just want to join the tables to your delete statement.. I wouldn't recommend using a subquery like that since dependent subqueries tend to be really slow

```
delete car from car
join owns o on o.liscense = car.liscense
join person p ON p.driver_id = o.driver_id
where p.name = 'John Smith'
```